# Setting max-width on an input element

Tags: css, width

Today I tried setting `max-width: 200px` on an `<input type="text">` but apparently it gets ignored by browsers.

If I set `width: 200px` then it properly gets applied (but doesn't get resized if `input` field gets resized smaller than 200px.

How do I apply `max-width` CSS property to input fields?

Comment: use percentage width as @TO4435 mentions, here's a js fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/looshi/oLwcyz6v/21/

Answer (score 3):

If you set max-width:200px; then you have to set the width in a relative unit like %. Because if you set width:200px the site of the input is not going to change;

this is an example

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
 <style type="text/css" media="screen">
  div{
   background-color: tomato;
   width: 100%;
   max-width: 1024px;
   margin: auto;
  }
  input{
   margin: auto;
   background-color: red;
   display: block;
   margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  input#no-fluid{
   border:2px black dotted;
   width: 200px;
   max-width: 300px;
  }
  input#fluid{
   border:2px black solid;
   width: 50%;
   max-width: 300px;
  }
 </style>
    </head>
    <body>
 <div>
  <input id="no-fluid" type="text">
  <input id="fluid" type="text">
 </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

The fluid input will change its width as you resize the screen, but only up to 300px(max-width). The non fluid on will keep its width, even if you resize the screen

**HOPE** this helps ***T04435***

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the other way around? In your example changing the `%` width does nothing, but changing the `px` does...

Comment: The `%` will only change the width when the viewport is below 600px. given that the max-width is set to 300px  and the width to 50%;

Answer (score 0):

Another thing you can do is set the `max-width` to `200px` and then you can set the width to anything using `width: 200px`. even if you exceed the `max-width`, its maximum width would always be `200px` and if you resize it to smaller than `200px` it will resize smaller to `200px`. And you can play around it with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d7n9qmgw/).